# How can I align bullet pointed examples within one example in the amsthm environment?

Tags: align, itemize, amsthm, examples, bullets

I am using amsthm to label examples. Rather than have each subsequent example separately, I would like to bullet point multiple examples within one labelled "example." So for instance, I might have 4+3 = 7, 2+4 = 6 and 3+1 = 4 all listed on separate lines with their own bullet point, but all three bullets within example 1.1.

How can I do this? Here is a minimal working example of code, where for the second example I have managed to get the desired result, but have failed for the first example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,  amssymb, amsthm, bm, graphicx,color}
 \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
 \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
 \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

 \theoremstyle{definition}
 \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
 \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\parskip 5mm

\parindent 1cm

\begin{document}


\begin{example}

\begin{align*}
\text{\textbullet} && & 13 \oplus 3  =  3  \\
\text{\textbullet} && & -4 \oplus 15  =  -4  \\
\end{align*}

\end{example}

\begin{example}

\begin{align*}     
    \text{\textbullet} && &\text{For } p = 2, \text{the p-adic (here 2-adic) valuation on } \frac{4}{9} \text{ is } 2, \text{ since } \frac{4}{9} = 2^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{9}, \\
    && &\text{where } 2 \nmid 1 \text{ and } 2 \nmid 9.\\
    \text{\textbullet} && &\text{For } p = 5, \text{the 5-adic valuation on } \frac{16}{125} \text{ is } -3, \text{ since } \frac{16}{125} = 5^{-3} \cdot \frac{16}{1}, \\
    && &\text{where } 5 \nmid 16 \text{ and } 5 \nmid 1.\\
\end{align*}

\end{example}

\end{document}
```

I have two questions. How do I replicate this second, working example 0.2 for any generic set of examples?
Secondly, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Why don't you use `itemize`? Why do you need `align` if you don't align the equations?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `itemize`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,  amssymb, amsthm, bm, graphicx,color}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

%\setlength{\parskip}{5mm} % should be flexible
%\setlength{\parindent}{1cm} % too wide

\begin{document}

\begin{example}\mbox{}
\begin{itemize}
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$13 \oplus 3  =  3$}
\item \makebox[\linewidth]{$-4 \oplus 15  =  -4$}
\end{itemize}
\end{example}

\begin{example}\mbox{}
\begin{itemize}
\item For $p = 2$, the $p$-adic (here $2$-adic) valuation on $\dfrac{4}{9}$ is $2$,
since $\dfrac{4}{9} = 2^{2} \cdot \dfrac{1}{9}$, where $2 \nmid 1$ and $2 \nmid 9$.

\item For $p = 5$, the $5$-adic valuation on $\dfrac{16}{125}$ is $-3$, since 
$\dfrac{16}{125} = 5^{-3} \cdot \dfrac{16}{1}$, where $5 \nmid 16$ and $5 \nmid 1$.
\end{itemize}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

No need to guess the line breaks. In the first case I'd avoid centering the math.

[image]

Compare with the more readable version below

```
\begin{example}\mbox{}
\begin{itemize}
\item $13 \oplus 3  =  3$
\item $-4 \oplus 15  =  -4$
\end{itemize}
\end{example}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- `flalign` helps you place `\textbullet` at the left of `\linewidth`
- `\eqmakebox` from `eqparbox` package helps for fine-tuning the alignments

Check this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts,  amssymb, amsthm, bm, graphicx,color}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\parskip 5mm

\parindent 1cm

\usepackage{eqparbox}


\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{example}
        
        \begin{flalign*}
            \text{\textbullet}
            &&
            13 & \oplus \eqmakebox[tag][l]{$3$} =  3
            &&
            \\
            \text{\textbullet}
            &&
            -4 & \oplus \eqmakebox[tag][l]{$15$} =  -4
            &&
        \end{flalign*}
        
    \end{example}
    
    \begin{example}
        
        \begin{flalign*}     
            \text{\textbullet}
            &&
            & \text{For } p = 2, \text{the p-adic (here 2-adic) valuation on } \frac{4}{9} \text{ is } 2, \text{ since } \frac{4}{9} = 2^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{9},
            \\
            &&
            & \text{where } 2 \nmid 1 \text{ and } 2 \nmid 9.
            \\
            \text{\textbullet}
            &&
            &\text{For } p = 5, \text{the 5-adic valuation on } \frac{16}{125} \text{ is } -3, \text{ since } \frac{16}{125} = 5^{-3} \cdot \frac{16}{1},
            \\
            &&
            &\text{where } 5 \nmid 16 \text{ and } 5 \nmid 1.
            \\
        \end{flalign*}
        
    \end{example}
    
\end{document}
```